# How to retrieve signed url from AWS Cloudfront in Xamarin Android/iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

We have a Xamarin Android and Xamarin iOS project that is attempting to use AWS S3 bucket and cloud front to retrieve images/data.  We implemented a successful POC using the .Net packages for AWS on a simple .NET console project.  However, once we've started using the libraries in Xamarin we don't appear to have access to some of the same classes we had.

We were using: AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.GetCannedSignedURL to create our signed urls.  That class doesn't seem to exist when the same packages are included in a Xamarin project.  I've tried looking at the Xamarin documentation on Amazon's site but they don't seem to include any information on using it with cloud front.  Only the default S3 access.

Has anyone done this before or know of where there might be documentation on using Cloud front with Xamarin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWSSDK CloudFront Library is created and maintained directly by Amazon so the best option you have is contact them.

I checked the repo and based on the [code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/CloudFront/Custom/_bcl%2Bcoreclr/AmazonCloudFrontUrlSigner.cs) it looks this utility is not part of Xamarin (as you just stated) and it seems this is the intention.

To find out if this is a bug you could enter their [Gitter](https://gitter.im/aws/aws-sdk-net) channel and ask or open an issue at [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues) so they can look at it.

Comment: Thanks i'll see if I can get in touch with someone from them.